# How to call a parent component method (or lift of state) from a custom React-Select MenuList component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have created a custom `MenuList` button ("Add New User") at the bottom of a `React-Select` element to allow for adding another user to the select list. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to handle the event once a new user is created. The codesandbox below contains a simplified version. Specifically, line 29 `this._loadData(randomId)` does not have the scope to access `this` of the parent component (obviously). My question is, how to I add a "handleEvent" property so that I can lift up state to the parent component for this custom `MenuList` component?

[image: Edit react-select-custom-event-handler]

Code snippet for the custom `MenuList` component allowing the user to add a new AppUser:

```
const MenuButtonAddNewUser = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.MenuList {...props}>
      {props.children}
      <div className="border-top text-center py-2">
        <a
          href="showModalUrl.action"
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Simluate opening a modal and adding a user
            let randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
            console.log(
              "Simluate loading modal and adding a user with id: " + randomId
            );

            // Tell parent componenent to reload the options from the database
            // and auto-select the new user
            // How do I gain access to "_loadData"???
            //this._loadData(randomId);
            console.log(
              "User added. Call 'this.loadData(" + randomId + ")' here!!"
            );
          }}
        >
          <i className="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus mr-1" /> Add New Agent
        </a>
      </div>
    </components.MenuList>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with react-select's API, but one approach you could take is to convert the class component to a function component. You could then move the `MenuButtonAddNewUser` component into the App component, this will give it access to everything App has access to.

CodeSandbox link with the suggestion: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-custom-event-handler-forked-n0v21o?file=/src/App-Hooks.js